# SQL Collation to support all European Languages plus Russian Cyrillic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

is it possible to have a collation on a table? I build a multi tenancy app and don't want for each country to have an extra database because the collation is different. I use SQL Server 2008 R2 if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use nvarchar. You won't be able to store multiple alphabets in varchar

Collation is code page for non-unicode data, and sorting and comparison for both. But you're still limited to 8 bit ASCII in the specified code page.

You *could* have different tables for each character set/alphabet, say on a 1 to 1 with some parent entity table. However, nvarchar is simpler unless you plan on having terabytes of text where the overhead is better than wide data.

Edit: my mistake, collation is always sorting and comparison.

Comment: Are you sure collation does not count for nvarchar? In the table designer i can change the collation for a nvarchar field from <database default> to anything.